# Which countries in Europe allow for the use of Pilot-Controlled-Light?

Tags: airport-lighting, eu

In Europe is very uncommon to see this feature at airports due to the local regulations in different countries, but still some are allowed and use this system. What countries allow for its use? Please name at least one airport for each country which uses it.

Comment: Are you really asking us to list every single airport in every country in Europe which uses this? That seems exceptionally broad.

Comment: @Ghilardi, unless you write a perfect question (hint: nobody does) there will always be some people that will have doubts on how to answer it, please accept it as a demonstration of the interest those people have in your questions.

Answer (score 2):

**Sweden** has numerous airports that use pilot controlled runway lights. Such lights are typically turned on by making a long (10 seconds or longer) transmission on the airport frequency, though variations exist.

Some examples of airports in Sweden that use PCL are:

- ESSD Borlänge/Dala Airport
- ESGE Borås
- ESSU Eskilstuna/Kjula
- ESNG Gällivare
- ESSG Ludvika
- ESKM Mora/Siljan
- ESND Sveg
- ESGT Trollhättan/Vänersborg
- ESKC Uppsala/Sundbro

For clarity's sake: This answer is not meant to imply that other countries do not allow for PCL, nor that all lighting on the airports listed is pilot controlled.